# Is the plane created by ($\int f_0^u f_1^{1-u},\int f_1^u f_0^{1-u})$ continuous?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$f_0$ and $f_1$ are two continuous density functions on $\mathbb{R}$. I wonder if $$(x,y):=\Bigg(\int f_0^u f_1^{1-u},\int f_1^u f_0^{1-u}\Bigg)$$ for all $f_0$ and $f_1$ is complete for some $0<u<1$? I cannot imagine such a space for any $0<u<1$. For $u=0.5$, it is however not difficult to see that it is a line $y=x$, c.f., the comments.  But I imagine that in two dimensional space $(x,y)$ there should be at least a closed space which is a subset of $[0,1]^2$ but I am not sure if there is a hole somewhere.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For $u=1/2$ it can be imagined: it's the diagonal $x=y$. To see that all points on the diagonal are realized, let $f_0=\chi_{[0,1]}$ and $f_1=\chi_{[t,t+1]}$ where $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @900 sit-ups a day yes thats right. It seems there is also symmetry for all $u$. Because one can replace $f_0$ with $f_1$. I guess for all $u$ we have $2$ curves starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(1,1)$, one concave and one convex and both curves are continuous. However, I don't know how to prove this.